# PHP: Can't access a definition from an included file?

Tags: php, php-include

I have a file `file_to_include.php` that contains variable definitions,

```
define("NAME", "John Doe");
```

But when I try to include it in my other file, `index.php`, using

```
include_once 'file_to_include.php';
```

and then echo my definition in `index.php` with

```
echo NAME;
```

All I see on the page is `NAME`, not `John Doe`.

I think definitions are global, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try defining it as .. public const $NAME = "John Doe" and check if it works

Comment: Doesn't make sense, it should work. Do both files have `<?php` at the beginning?

Comment: Both files have <?php at the beginning, and not the shorthand <? tag. And trying to use public const $NAME gives me the same result.

Comment: enable `display_errors`, and see if `include_once` throws a `warning`.

Comment: No need to use public const . `define()` should work. Something else is buggy. Hmm...

Comment: Yes, i agree.. check for errors/warnings.

Comment: edit: Aha! PHP can't find my file. Let me do some more poking around...

Comment: include_once(): Failed opening '/constants/db_config.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/controller/db_connect.php on line 6

Comment: Problem solved, posting as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe wrong path, look what the PHP's `inlcude_path` is look like. PHP's `include` and `include_once` will continue, even the requested file is found or not.

You should keep that in mind, that `require` and `require_once` will break the execution if the file is not found, in contrast to `include` and `include_one` will not.

The [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) says:

> require is identical to include except upon failure it will also produce a fatal E_COMPILE_ERROR level error. In other words, it will halt the script whereas include only emits a warning (E_WARNING) which allows the script to continue.